# What is the equivalent of float8( e.g. in postgres) for mysql

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql

I have a mysql database and i want to insert values similar to this one `12,3456.78`. I tried using the float and double type but the result is rounded to `12` and using decimal is still not helping, i get `12.0`. I saw in another database( postgres database) that for that type of column you can use the `float8` but i dont know how to use it for a mysql database because i only have 3 options for real numbers( float, double, decimal and i wrote the outputs in the beginning).

How can i solve this without changing the database?

Comment: not with you why is decimal not a suitable option?

Comment: @P.Salmon i want the value to look like the one i put as example with dot and comma and using decimal i lost the comma

Comment: in that case varchar or char of some sort in mysql but you won't be able to do arithmetic on it directly.

Comment: Numeric types have no commas or dots, they're binary values. Dots and commas are *only* used when formatting the values as strings, or parsing strings into numbers. When that happens the *developer* specifies what culture, language or separator to use

Comment: `the result is rounded to 12` this means the parsing code is incorrect, not the type. Where did the text come from, where is it being converted? That's where the bug is, not in the type. Storing strings instead of actual numeric or date values is a very serious database bug

Comment: Is the application constructing INSERT/UPDATE statements by concatenating strings for example? That exposes the application to SQL injection bugs *and* conversion bugs, because the number will be converted using the *client's* language. The solution is to use queries with parameters instead of concatenating input

Comment: The guys at MySQL did write a manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/floating-point-types.html

Answer (score 2):

By default, the dot is interpreted as the decimal separator and comma as a column/value separator. As a result, you probably inserted `12` into one column and `3456.78` somewhere else: [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KJFYhIfZ)

```sql
create table test (f float,d decimal(65,2));
insert into test select 12,345.6;
select * from test;
```

| f | d |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 345.60 |

That being said, you probably want a text-to-number parsing function and a [`CAST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) on input and number-to-text [`FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) on output:

```sql
TRUNCATE test;

INSERT INTO test 
SELECT CAST(REPLACE('12,3456.78',',','') AS FLOAT),
       CAST(REPLACE('12,3456.78',',','') AS DECIMAL(65,2));

SELECT FORMAT(f,2) AS f, 
       FORMAT(d,2) AS d, 
       FORMAT(f,2,'de_DE') AS f_de, 
       FORMAT(d,2,'de_DE') AS d_de
FROM test;
```

| f | d | f_de | d_de |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123,456.78 | 123,456.78 | 123.456,78 | 123.456,78 |

You haven't shared your actual code but as [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77358834/what-is-the-equivalent-of-float8-e-g-in-postgres-for-mysql/77359049#comment136378643_77358834) [@Panagiotis Kanavos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/134204/panagiotis-kanavos), this sort of problem does look like it could have been caused by constructing a query through string interpolation. Most client libraries and ORMs offer ways to automatically and safely handle the formatting, conversion and transfer in/out/between your sources. It's not only more [secure](https://google.com/search?q=mysql%20sql%20injection), it's also faster and more convenient.

Comment: so there is no way to use that kind of value in just one column? the thing is i want multiple columns with that type so i can do like sum or other operations

Comment: @Mega numbers have no dots or commas. `float8` is a 64-bit value, with no individual digits, much less dots. Where did the *text* come from? This has nothing to do with the data type

Comment: the data is coming from one excel that has the columns set to decimal number and then using php i insert in database

Comment: @Mega Both Excel and RDMBS like MySQL actually don't really store the dots and commas - they store the actual number in a binary format. The dots and commas are a result of formatting the underlying value for human readability. If you want the two systems to interface through text, it's best to only leave the dot as the decimal separator and strip things the commas, apostrophes, unit indicators. [You can configure Excel to not produce the thousand separators in the first place](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/show-or-hide-the-thousands-separator-b9f8aee0-ef50-42e5-8fd7-6e3ab1493876)

Answer (score 1):

in mysql we can use double

```
CREATE TABLE test_table (
    test_column_name DOUBLE
);
```

Comment: Link to the manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.1/en/floating-point-types.html